# Getting an error while trying to load a cucumber test (undefined method `as_json' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I upgraded my VM environment with the following versions:

- cucumber 2.4.0
- selenium-webdriver 3.7.0
- ruby 2.4.1
- chrome 62.0.3202.94
- ChromeDriver 2.33.506092

my env.rb is configured with the following attributes:

```
    $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
    $browser.manage.window.maximize
```

I'm trying to run any test and i'm getting the following error:

```
    undefined method `as_json' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.7.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:111:in `create_capabilities'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.7.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:33:in `initialize'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.7.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `new'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.7.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `for'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.7.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:84:in `for'
    /home/glasner/repos/portal_automation/features/support/env.rb:193:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:57:in `times'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/retriable-3.1.1/lib/retriable.rb:57:in `retriable'
    /home/glasner/repos/portal_automation/features/support/env.rb:189:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load_code_file'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:142:in `load_file'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `block in load_files!'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `each'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:253:in `load_step_definitions'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:61:in `run!'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /home/glasner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I tried using different version of all of the above but it seems that the problem is that new "options" configurations for the chrome browser.
Which option should I use in order to solve that problem?

Thank you! :)

**UPDATE**:

Found the answer to the problem.
I had a method for running the tests in a headless mode that initialize the options variable, but that wasn't good enough.
options variable should be initialized before we configure the driver, as such:

```
   options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
   $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
   $browser.manage.window.maximize
```

Comment: Found the answer to my question.